# Can I choose how to pronounce my own name?

Tags: fraud, freedom-of-speech, name, language

This is more a thought experiment than anything else...

Let's say my name is 'Alan Temaficoni', and, as a joke, I decide to pronounce 'Alan' as 'Professor', making my name sound like 'Professor Temaficoni'. Are there any laws that prohibit me from doing so? I can imagine that if I were to do this in order to perpetrate some kind of fraud (I'm not thinking of doing this!), I could encounter legal challenges.

I've done some searching on this, both here and on the Internet at large, and have come up with a total blank.

Thank you for your thoughts!

Addenda in response to comments:

1. I'm not specifically referring to any particular jurisdiction. If there are any rules relating to this, I would imagine that they would presumably follow the same lines.
2. I'm not talking about aliases. I'm referring specifically to the latitude allowed to anyone who might choose to insist that their legal name be pronounced in a manner that would be substantially different from the way in which others might do so.

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: Also, are you asking specifically whether the legal situation would be affected by whether you claimed that your use of a fake name, or false credentials, was actually just "pronouncing your name differently"?

Comment: Reminds me when my uncle taught my little cousin how to spell his name... U-G-L-Y. Are you asking about pronunciation, or is this about aliases? For example my legal name isn't "Ron", but that's what I prefer to be called.

Comment: In what situation is this? If we are friends chatting, and you say to me 'just call me Professor' that is one situation. If I am a police officer and I need to identify your full name for a legal reason,  it's a completely different situation. For legal purposes your name is defined by how you write it, not how you say it.

Comment: @Sneftel regarding your 'also' -- I'm referring specifically to the legality of choosing how one's name is pronounced. As I already said in my original question, I acknowledge that asserting that one is someone different from one's legal name purely on the basis of how the name is pronounced could be considered fraud.

Comment: @Brandin thanks for your input. Yes, it's just your 'friends chatting' situation. See the second paragraph of my original question.

Comment: @Brandin regarding "For legal purposes your name is defined by how you write it, not how you say it." – off topic, but that's interesting... where I'm required to provide a signature but I'm only offered a digital tablet to enter it, since I find it utterly impossible to replicate my handwritten signature using a finger on a tablet, I recently resorted to signing my name as simply 'X', in silent protest, on the grounds that there's no way to prove that the scrawl left by me in an attempt to 'sign' wasn't in fact done by someone else.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not allowed to claim that "Give me your wallet or else I will shot you" is just how you want to pronounce your name and because of that you are innocent if people spontaneously gift you your wallets.

Comment: "If there are any rules relating to this, I would imagine that they would presumably follow the same lines": not really.  Some jurisdictions have laws governing the use of academic titles, and asserting that "Alan" is pronounced "Professor" is likely to fall afoul of such laws.  In jurisdictions without laws like that, it's likely to be acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No jurisdiction imposes penalties for "mispronunciation", however conceived. Some jurisdictions have official language academies which sanctioned by the government, but they are limited to a declaration of what is "official". Some countries have [naming laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_law), according to which in Norway you shall not name your child Zaphod Beeblebrox, but Knut Toresen is available. No law of Norway requires you to pronounce the name the way it is pronounced in "Standard Norwegian" (if there were such a thing), or even the way it is pronounced in any known dialect. While you have a right to mispronounce the name however you want, you cannot use this practice as a pretext for evading legal responsibilities, thus you must respond to legal service duly delivered to you under the name Knut Toresen, etc. To slightly change the scenario, if you decide to pronounce Knut Toresen as Tore Knutsen, you cannot disaffirm a contract where your name was given orally and you pronounced Tore Knutsen, intending that the person should write "Knut Toresen".